# Can I set cursor position in vim mapping?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to set the cursor position for a mapping? For example:

`nmap erb; <%=  %>`

I want to set the cursor after the equals sign. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

```
inoremap erb; <%= %><left><left><left>
nnoremap erb; a<%= %><left><left><left>
```

Shall do it.

NB: there exist several plugins that help defining such mappings. For instance, with [lh-brackets](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhBrackets), the definition would be done with:

```
Brackets <%= \ %> -trigger=erb;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want this mapping to insert "`<%= =>`", so try something like this:

```
:nmap erb; i<%= =><esc>hh
```